# webhook woocommerce to mysql via php

Tags: php, arrays, json

Hello I start in PHP so be indulgent
I have a wordpress site with woocommerce

this one allows me to create WEBHOOK in order that every time a certain action is done it sends a json file to an address of my choice

on the other hand i have a crm that does not have an API and I want to connect to woocommerce to receive data only

so i will want to create a php script that translates the format received by woocommerce and sends the data on the crm mysql table and row.

I have already seen tutorial on php //: input but I can not make it work
Thanks for your help

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "testapi";
$password = "*****";
$dbname = "testapi";

// Create connection
$connect = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($connect->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $connect->connect_error);
} 
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"),true);
var_dump(($data));




    foreach($data as $row) {
       $sql = "INSERT INTO json(id, parent_id) VALUES 
       ('".$row["id"]."', '".$row["parent_id"]."'); ";

    }
    if ($connect->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully <br>";
    } else {
     echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $connect->error;
    }

   $connect->close();
  }
  print_r($data);
  ?>
```

I wrote this code it works but it returns 0 because wordpress sends the json in this way (json_content) and my code works only if I add [(json_content)]

sorry for my English

Answer (score 0):

Then all you would need to do is this :

```
$data = json_decode([file_get_contents("php://input")],true);
```